# PHPMailer: Utilizando o campo email como remetente

Tags: phpmailer, php

Estou com uma dúvida, tem como eu utilizar o e-mail que foi preenchido no campo "E-MAIL:" do formulário como remetente? Preciso que quando apertar no botão de resposta da caixa postal ele preencha com o email que for preenchido no formulário...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é preciso colocar o email como remetente. Você pode utilizar a função `replyTo` para isso. Ela tem intuito que quando o email for respondido pela caixa postal, a resposta vá para o email informado na função `replyTo` ao invés do email que enviou o email.

```
$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@email.com', 'Reply to name');
```